# Python set not empty but pop returns empty?

Tags: python, set

I saw a similar problem with multithreading but this isn't even multithreading, it's just straight up populating a set and then popping.

I print out the set and then immediately after, try to print out the pop of the set. but it says the set is empty when i see something like this for the set print out:

`set(['', 'asdf', 'asdf, 'asdf'])`

Comment: Please provide context - otherwise your question is pointless

Comment: In your example you forgot a ' after the second 'asdf'.

Comment: When you pop an element, you remove the element and return it to the caller. If you pop all elements, your set become empty...

Comment: Show us the code and the exact set.

Comment: Also you should know that a set will not allow duplicate elements like a list will.  So the resulting set will only have two elements, the empty string and 'asdf'.

Comment: i've changed the code too much to find out what the problem was. len(set) returned 100 but set.pop() gave an error....at any rate please close!

Answer (score 3):

```
pop(...)
    Remove and return an arbitrary set element.
    Raises KeyError if the set is empty.
```

Since you have an empty string in your set, it is highly possible that a `foo.pop()` returns this empty string and printing an empty string gives you nothing.

Comment: If "it says the set is empty" isn't the KeyError mentioned above, this question was even worse than I thought. Returning an empty string it a lot different than the "KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'" you'll see calling `pop()` on a empty set.